# Web server www files storage

Tags: web-server, nginx, ubuntu-10.04, files

I am currently setting up a few virtual machines with Ubuntu Server 10.04.02 on them and was wondering what is the best place to store the www files.

I will be using nginx and I see that the default `/var/www` can be changed to something else. Cpanel uses `/home/username/public_html`. Is this a good way to store websites?

I would like a simple directory that is easy to remember and to backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cpanel is designed to mantain different users(customers) with their own virtual hosts, databases and FTP accounts. Therefor it creates system users and document root is in /home/, which is natural.

Apache has default document root in /var/www, and if you don't have any special urges, you can let it there. Then you can make subdirectories for every virtual host, like this:

```
/var/www/example.com
/var/www/mail.example.com
/var/www/someothervhost.com
```

Nagios installation is stored outside of /var deeply in /usr, so you don't have to worry about mixing Nagios files with your own.

Comment: OK, just wondering how people like to do it. Cheers =]

Answer (score 0):

As mkudlacek says ~/public_html is intended for per-user content.

The /var/www location reflects a filesystem layout where webserving is just one of many services provided by a system (on most Unix systems you'll also find /var/mail, /var/ftp etc). Most webservers are single-purpose devices, so using this directory is perhaps not very appropriate - OTOH it is where most people would **expect** to find the website.

There are different considerations which may affect the location of the web content (running on a seperate filesystem with noatime, a shared filesystem, a high speed SAN...) but within your virtual machine, I'd recommend sticking with /var/www

Answer (score 0):

It can be anythintbh, just make sure that the directory has proper permissions.
I use this format generally:

/var/www/site.com/public